# Applicative instance requires 1 AND 0 arguments

Tags: haskell, stack, monads, state-monad

I was going through "Learn Yourself a Haskell" and am trying to implement the "Heathrow to London" problem [1] in a Monadic way (instead of folds or explicit recursions). 
[1] http://learnyouahaskell.com/functionally-solving-problems#heathrow-to-london

My question is this: both `instance Applicative Route where` and `instance Applicative Route a where` makes GHC complain as below. So including a type parameter is wrong, but not including is also wrong. How do I overcome this by minimal change to the code (its implementation idea)? See implementation below the GHC error.

```
Prelude> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( heathrowToLondon.hs, interpreted )

heathrowToLondon.hs:70:10: error:
    • Expecting one fewer argument to ‘Applicative Route’
      Expected kind ‘k0 -> Constraint’,
        but ‘Applicative Route’ has kind ‘Constraint’
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Applicative Route a’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( heathrowToLondon.hs, interpreted )

heathrowToLondon.hs:70:10: error:
    • The type synonym ‘Route’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Applicative Route’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

My implementation was this: think of each street (one street above, one street below and the crossing avenue) costs as a `Street`, then think of `Route` as all the route until now as well as the cumulative costs of going `Up` or `Down` next. Then, `mempty` or `pure` for `Route` would be something like `([], (0,0))`. We define a binary operation `join` to `Route`, then we can get `>=` by using `fmap` and `join`.  Partial code below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-} 

import Data.List
import Data.List.Extra (chunksOf)
import Control.Monad

-- Try this:
-- solvePath [50, 10, 30, 5, 90, 20, 40, 2, 25, 10, 8]

data Path = Up | Down deriving (Show, Eq, Read)
type Costs a = (a, a)
type Street a = [a]
type Route a = ([Path], Costs a)

-- Monadic!?
toRoute :: (Num a, Ord a) => Street a -> Route a
toRoute [x,y,z] = ([], (min x (y+z), min y (x+z)))
toRoute _ = ([], (0,0))

instance Applicative Route where -- putting or not putting this `a` here doesn't work
  pure x = toRoute x -- turns [1,2,5] Street value 
  f <*> g = undefined


-- Irrelevant to this question but does the job
-- Using explicit recursion
solvePath :: (Num a, Ord a) => Street a -> [Path]
solvePath xs = reverse . crossStreet (0,0) [] $ 0:xs

crossStreet :: (Num a, Ord a) => Costs a -> [Path] -> Street a -> [Path]
crossStreet (a,b) rd street
  | null street        = rd
  | a > b             = crossStreet (a',b') (Down:rd) street'
  | a == b && a' >= b' = crossStreet (a',b') (Down:rd) street'
  | otherwise          = crossStreet (a',b') (Up:rd) street'
  where (a',b') = (a + min x (y+z), b + min y (x+z))
        (x:y:z:street') = street



-- Using folds
solvePath' = reverse . fst . foldl' crossStreet' ([], (0,0)) . chunksOf 3 . (0:)

crossStreet' :: (Num a, Ord a) => Route a -> Street a -> Route a
crossStreet' (ps, (a,b)) [] = (ps, (a,b))
crossStreet' (ps, (a,b)) [x,y,z] = (ps', (a', b'))
  where (a',b') = (a + min x (y+z), b + min y (x+z))
        ps' = p:ps
        p | a > b || ((a==b) && a' >= b') = Down
          | otherwise                     = Up
```

### Edit #1

Based on comments, I changed the definition for route into `RouteM` using `data`, and now the original complaint is solved. However, I still need to figure out how to implement the `<*>` though.

```
data RouteM a = RouteM {getPath :: [Path], getCost :: Costs a} deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

-- Monadic!?
toRouteM :: (Num a, Ord a) => Street a -> RouteM a
toRouteM [x,y,z] = RouteM [] (min x (y+z), min y (x+z))
toRouteM _ = RouteM [] (0, 0)

instance Functor RouteM where -- putting or not putting this `a` here doesn't work
  fmap f r = RouteM (getPath r) (f . fst $ getCost r, f . snd $ getCost r)

instance Applicative RouteM where -- putting or not putting this `a` here doesn't work
  pure x = RouteM [] (x, x)
  f <*> r = undefined
```

Comment: There are a couple problems here. First of all, you can’t really define instances on type aliases (you can with GHC extensions, but it’s the same as defining an instance on the underlying type). You should change `type Route a = ...` to `data Route a = Route ...` to create a fresh type to define instances on. Additionally, while `instance Applicative Route ...` is correct in this case, it’s worth pointing out that you probably wanted to try `instance Applicative (Route a)`, *not* `instance Applicative Route a`. The latter is syntax for a multi-parameter typeclass.

Comment: @AlexisKing That should probably be turned into an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your Route type /is/ an applicative, or why it should be.

What would `Route path (f,g) <*> Route path' (x,y)` mean?

You are missing info you need here. (Namely the cost on the Up/Down street.)

Your Route/RouteM type doesn't compose the way an applicative should.

Also I would define `type Block a = {getUp::a,getDown:a,getCross:a)`
and `type Street a = [Block]`. Then define a `Route a -> Block a -> Route a`.